# Is it possible to hava an alternately colored listbox in Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am trying to code the listbox in such a way that all list items are alternately coloured. But I realised that there is no property for this. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need owner-drawn ListBoxes and subclassing.  If you hunt around you can find a number of projects that have done the work for you already.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can color the items but you can change the font color and background color and you can always make your own custom control